# Mark parameters as NOT nullable in C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, parameters, null

Is there a simple attribute or data contract that I can assign to a function parameter that prevents `null` from being passed in C#/.NET?  Ideally this would also check at compile time to make sure the literal `null` isn't being used anywhere for it and at run-time throw `ArgumentNullException`.

Currently I write something like ...

```
if (null == arg)
  throw new ArgumentNullException("arg");
```

... for every argument that I expect to not be `null`.

On the same note, is there an opposite to `Nullable<>` whereby the following would fail:

```
NonNullable<string> s = null; // throw some kind of exception
```

Comment: With recent versions of C#, using "nameof()" works better:
throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(arg));
That way, if you refactor the name, if ripples into your throw statement

Comment: C# 8 now supports nullable reference types which is a compiler option you can turn on in your project.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references

Answer (score 72, accepted):

There's nothing available at compile-time, unfortunately.

I have a bit of a [hacky solution](https://web.archive.org/web/20081231232311/http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/10/06/non-nullable-reference-types.aspx) which I posted on my blog recently, which uses a new struct and conversions.

In .NET 4.0 with the [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/contracts/) stuff, life will be a lot nicer. It would still be quite nice to have actual language syntax and support around non-nullability, but the code contracts will help a lot.

I also have an extension method in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) called ThrowIfNull which makes it a bit simpler.

One final point - any reason for using "`if (null == arg)`" instead of "`if (arg == null)`"? I find the latter easier to read, and the problem the former solves in C doesn't apply to C#.

Comment: > There's nothing available at compile-time, unfortunately.  
> ...  
> It would still be quite nice to have actual language syntax and support around non-nullability

I agree. I would also like to see compile-time errors being raised.

Comment: @Jon, doesn't "if (arg = null)" work if there happens to be an implicit cast to bool defined?  I admit it may seem perverse, but it does compile...

Comment: @ThomasS.Trias: Yes, in that incredibly obscure edge case, *combined* with there being a typo, combined with a lack of tests around that code, you'd end up with a problem. By that point I think you have bigger problems though :)

Comment: @Jon: Granted.  I guess I will give up my beloved Yoda conditions.  :-)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make `NotNullable<>` inherit from T and override the assignment operator for `object` and then call the base class version after checking that the parameter for the assignment is not null? Or instead set the assignment to a default value and call the base.

Comment: @MrUniverse: Well that's introducing all kinds of things that aren't feasible in C#...

Answer (score 39):

I know I'm incredibly late to this question, but I feel the answer will become relevant as the latest major iteration of C# comes closer to release, then released.  In C# 8.0 a major change will occur, C# will assume *all* types are considered not null.

According to Mads Torgersen:

> The problem is that null references are so useful. In C#, they are the
>   default value of every reference type. What else would the default
>   value be? What other value would a variable have, until you can decide
>   what else to assign to it? What other value could we pave a freshly
>   allocated array of references over with, until you get around to
>   filling it in?
>
> Also, sometimes null is a sensible value in and of itself. Sometimes
>   you want to represent the fact that, say, a field doesn’t have a
>   value. That it’s ok to pass “nothing” for a parameter. The emphasis is
>   on sometimes, though. And herein lies another part of the problem:
>   Languages like C# don’t let you express whether a null right here is a
>   good idea or not.

So the resolution outlined by Mads, is:

> 1. We believe that it is more common to want a reference not to be null. Nullable reference types
>      would be the rarer kind (though we don’t have good data to tell us by
>      how much), so they are the ones that should require a new annotation.
> 2. The language already has a notion of – and a syntax for – nullable value types. The analogy between the two would make the language
>      addition conceptually easier, and linguistically simpler.
> 3. It seems right that you shouldn’t burden yourself or your consumer with cumbersome null values unless you’ve actively decided that you
>      want them. Nulls, not the absence of them, should be the thing that
>      you explicitly have to opt in to.

An example of the desired feature:

```
public class Person
{
     public string Name { get; set; } // Not Null
     public string? Address { get; set; } // May be Null
}
```

The preview is available for Visual Studio 2017, 15.5.4+ preview.

Comment: Does anyone know if this ever ended up being part of C# 8.0?

Comment: @TroySteven Yes it is, you have to opt into it though through settings in Visual Studio.

Comment: @TroySteven Here is the documentation on it.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references

Comment: Nice, so it looks like you have to enable it before it starts working, that's nice for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 20):

I know this is a VERY old question, but this one was missing here:

If you use ReSharper/Rider you may use the [Annotated Framework](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_analysis.html#Annotated_Framework).

**Edit**: I just got a random -1 for this answer. That's fine. Just be aware it is *still* valid, even though it's not the recommended approach for C#8.0+ projects anymore (to understand why, see [Greg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48690719/158074)).

Comment: Interestingly, that by default your compiled application will not have reference to the JetBrains.Annotations.dll so you don't have to distributed it with the application: [How to use JetBrains Annotations to improve ReSharper inspections](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/08/12/how-to-use-jetbrains-annotations-to-improve-resharper-inspections/)

Answer (score 9):

Check out the validators in the enterprise library.  You can do something like :

```
private MyType _someVariable = TenantType.None;
[NotNullValidator(MessageTemplate = "Some Variable can not be empty")]
public MyType SomeVariable {
    get {
        return _someVariable;
    }
    set {
        _someVariable = value;
    }
}
```

Then in your code when you want to validate it:

```
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validator myValidator = ValidationFactory.CreateValidator<MyClass>();

ValidationResults vrInfo = InternalValidator.Validate(myObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

not the prettiest but:

```
public static bool ContainsNullParameters(object[] methodParams)
{
     return (from o in methodParams where o == null).Count() > 0;
}
```

you could get more creative in the ContainsNullParameters method too:

```
public static bool ContainsNullParameters(Dictionary<string, object> methodParams, out ArgumentNullException containsNullParameters)
       {
            var nullParams = from o in methodParams
                             where o.Value == null
                             select o;

            bool paramsNull = nullParams.Count() > 0;


            if (paramsNull)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var param in nullParams)
                    sb.Append(param.Key + " is null. ");

                containsNullParameters = new ArgumentNullException(sb.ToString());
            }
            else
                containsNullParameters = null;

            return paramsNull;
        }
```

of course you could use an interceptor or reflection but these are easy to follow/use with little overhead

Comment: Very bad practice using such queries:
`return (from o in methodParams where o == null).Count() > 0;`

Use:
`return methodParams.Any(o=>o==null);`
it will be much faster at big collections

Comment: Why pass out the exception? Why not just throw it?

Answer (score -4):

Ok this reply is a bit late, but here is how I am solving it:

```
public static string Default(this string x)
{
    return x ?? "";
}
```

Use this exension method then you can treat null and empty string as the same thing.

E.g.

```
if (model.Day.Default() == "")
{
    //.. Do something to handle no Day ..
}
```

Not ideal I know as you have to remember to call default everywhere but it is one solution.

Comment: how is this any better/easier than the (x == null) checks? or the String.IsNotNullOrEmpty function.

Comment: Not much better than `string.IsNotNullOrEmpty` really other than the sugar of having the thing you care about on the left. Can be fed into other functions (length, concatenation) etc. Marginally better.

Comment: @MartinCapodici Also, this creates an illusion that you are safe to call instance method (`Default()`) on a ***null*** (`model.Day`). I know extension methods are not checked against null, but my eyes are not aware and they already imagined the `?` into the code: `model?.Day?.Default()` :)