# Obligation for field to have a value

Tags: c#, design-patterns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mark parameters as NOT nullable in C#/.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291340/mark-parameters-as-not-nullable-in-c-net)

For example, I have a simple class with one field:

```
class User
{
    private readonly string _name;

    public User(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get { return _name; } }
}
```

How to forbid to set `name` argument to `null`, because `User` should always have some name? I can't to do such check inside constructor, because anyway instance will be created. Should I use some pattern (make private constructor and add method to generate instances... don't know how this pattern called) or there is any language support to do this trick?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I'm interested in creating new instances (checking inside constructor), not a checking simple function arguments.

Comment: same options apply to both cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the check in the constructor: if the `name` argument is `null` then throw an `ArgumentNullException`.

> I can't to do such check inside constructor, because anyway instance
>   will be created.

An object instance will not be created if the constructor throws an exception so you don't have to worry about having an invalid user:

```
User user = null;

try
{
     user = new User(null); //throws ArgumentNullException
}
catch (ArgumentNullException)
{
    //user == null is true.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two solutions:

- **Throwing exception at constructor** in case of a `NULL` value. This is generally considered a bad thing. **(According to Jeffrey Richter's book)**
- **Code contracts**

Comment: Why is it generally considered a bad thing? Code contracts do the same.

Comment: Since when is throwing an exception from ctor considered bad? o.O

Comment: Give me a few minutes, I amtrying to find the link

Comment: It is in Jeff Richter's CLR via c#

Comment: If we enforced all rules and policies out there we would never get anything done. :)