Dereferencing a nullable type
I've written a function that parses some arguments into a valid "thing". If the arguments can't be parsed into a valid thing, then this function will return a null.
I'm accessing the valid "thing" by casting it to the specific type, but I'm wondering if there is a concise way to "dereference" the thing instead of casting.
private Nullable<Thing> GetTheThing(string arg) 
{
    if (s == "") 
    {
        return new Thing(...);
    } 
    else 
    {
        return null;
    }
}

// ...snip...

var t = GetTheThing("asd")

if (t == null) 
{
    throw Exception("Thing could not be made from this arg");
}

// This function take a "Thing" as it's argument, NOT a NULLABLE.
// Casting just seems so brute force, I feel like t should already know what it is, and I've checked for null, so why can't I just do something like *t?
DoSomethingWithTheThing((Thing)t);


Look at the Boolean HasValue property and the T-typed Value property of Nullable<T>.

"...I feel like t should already know what it is..." t is of type Nullable or Thing?  You can either change your method definition to accept Thing? or cast as you're currently doing, or you could make the return type of your GetTheThing method Thing, instead of Nullable ----- to simplify everything here, I would just make the method return type Thing and add your exception inside the method, remove the return null, and remove your null check

Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29184887/best-way-to-check-for-null-parameters-guard-clauses answer your question? var t = GetTheThing("asd") ?? throw new Exception(…); (you can write Nullable<Thing> as Thing?, by the way)

do you mean Nullable<Thing> as the value-type nullable (such as int?) or is it "pseudo-code" for all nullables?

Do you always throw an exception in case of null? If yes, I would add throwing it inside the function. If not, I would rename the function as "TryGetTheThing".

@Kevin Making the GetThingMethod accept Thing? is doable, but I explicitly want to do the null check BEFORE calling that method. That method should only accept valid Thing arguments. My question here is not about convention or best practices, but syntax. Casting a known non-null nullable value to seems like a heavy handed way to just get the value from the variable. Does C# not support a shorter dereference syntax just like *t ?

The only different syntax for the cast itself is the "as" keyword...so you could do DoSomethingWithTheThing(t as Thing).

I'm relatively new to C#, is the as keyword just a sugared version of the cast with no functional difference? And just to be clear, a Nullable type is not just a convenience for a null, but a completely distinct entire type and there is no way to dereference like I would a normal pointer?

with classes/reference-types, nullable types are more of "a convenience". with value types (structs), they are a strictly different type. you can use .Value to access a struct's inner value, but it will throw if there isn't actually a value. if you have a test for null first, the compiler should see that it is safe to access .Value. if you don't test for null first you might get a warning. in situations where you know that there is a value but the compiler does not you can use thing!.Value to override the warning.

@user22335954 no, as is not sugared cast. You will get null on a failure in the first case, exception in the latter.

Normally I would write it something like this:
var maybeThing = MaybeGetThing("asd");
if (maybeThing is not { } thing)
    throw Exception("Thing could not be made from this arg");

// do something with thing which will be non-nullable

MaybeGetThing (this could also be named GetThingOrDefault or GetThingOrNull):
Thing? MaybeGetThing(string arg) {
   if (arg == ...)
      return null;

   return new Thing(...);
}

To do this without "casting", and might be what you're looking for by saying 'dereference' you could do this, but I would not normally write it this way myself. Basically you can use .Value if you know that there should be a value. This works only with nullable structs and not nullable reference types. Saying nullablestruct.Value is kind of like saying "GetValueOrThrow", since you are asserting that the value should exist, and to throw an exception otherwise.
var maybeThing = MaybeGetThing("asd");
if (maybeThing is null)
    throw Exception("Thing could not be made from this arg");

DoSomethingWithTheThing(maybeThing.Value);

Some other kinds of methods that can be useful as well:
Thing GetThingOrThrow(string arg) {
   var maybeThing = MaybeGetThing(arg);
   if (maybeThing is not { } thing)
      throw ...;

   return thing;
}

bool TryGetThing(string arg, [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out Thing result) {
   result = MaybeGetThing(arg);
   return result is { };
}

bool CantGetThing(string arg, [MaybeNullWhen(true)] out Thing result) {
   result = MaybeGetThing(arg);
   return result is null;
}

The MaybeNullWhen attribute should provide IDE warnings when you use it the wrong way.
Example:
if (CantGetThing("arg", out var thing)) {
   // can't use thing, it is null
   return;
}
// can use thing since we returned in the case that it was null


I thought this was a simple question about syntax but you added 3 additional methods with additional critique of the grammar and naming of some toy example code. Additionally, you didn't even call your own methods in a way to answer the original question.

@user22335954 the first code I wrote was how to "answer the original question". if (maybeThing is not { } thing), maybeThing will be nullable and thing will not be nullable, which I indicated. is it possible that you don't have nullable references turned on?

@user22335954 I see that in your example Thing must be a struct, but my example should still work in that case also. I have included an example without "casting"; otherwise I don't know what you're looking for.

I don't follow what is not {} thing means syntactically, but you haven't given the code I'm interested in after that. I want to know how to USE (dereference) the maybeThing now that I know that it is not in fact null. How do I dereference maybeThing to get an actual Thing?

@user22335954 if (maybeThing is not { } thing) creates a new variable thing that is non-nullable and useable only on the correct branch of the if (where it is known to be not null). as I added you can also use maybeThing.Value. that is how to "dereference maybeThing to get an actual Thing" (assuming Thing is a struct; won't work for class types), but I don't usually use it that way with the new pattern matching syntax.

@user22335954 also to be more clear is { } means basically "has a value" or "is not null" (or really "is an object/value"). I negate it to is not { } so that the if branch is the exceptional case (where we throw) and then after the if (assuming we threw or returned) becomes the valid case, where the value is known to be not null. the compiler knows this syntax and should tell you if you use the value on the wrong branch.

You could accomplish this with out variables.
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        if (TryGetTheThing("thing", out Thing thing))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I got a thing here");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thing will be null");
        }   
    }
    
    public static bool TryGetTheThing(string s, out Thing thing)
    {
        if (s == "thing")
        {
            thing = new Thing();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            thing = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public class Thing
{
}

Working fiddle here.
But if you insist on making it nullable, that's doable too.
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var t = GetTheThing("");
        
        if (t == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Thing could not be made from this arg");
        }
        else
        {
            t.DoSomething();
        }
    }
    
    private static Thing? GetTheThing(string s)
    {
        if (s == "")
        {
            return new Thing();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public class Thing
{
    public void DoSomething () { Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!"); }
}

Working fiddle here.

I didn't downvote you. Your function signature is weak, it should be [MaybeNull(false)] on out parameter.
