# C# and nullable flag/annotation?

Tags: c#, nullable

Does C# have Nullable annotation's?

For example in Java

```
public @Nullable <T extends BaseJsonClass> T getModel(String saveKey, Class<T> type) {
```

Now when the developer tries to call

```
Object.getModel().someMethod()
```

The compiler will warn them that they are not checking for null.

I'm aware of the `?` mark at the end of var names in C# like `someObject?` but the problem with this is that it can be tricky/annoying/JSON models when vars are being used in many places.

Comment: Try this, seems the same to the same request. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291340/mark-parameters-as-not-nullable-in-c-net)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#: How to Implement and use a NotNull and CanBeNull attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792531/c-how-to-implement-and-use-a-notnull-and-canbenull-attribute)

Comment: I doubt if something like this is available in c#

Comment: Sounds like [code-contract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C# does not have anything like that - such feature is not a part of the language (yet).

However, if you use ReSharper, you can utilize its [Value and Nullability Analysis](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Code_Analysis__Value_Analysis.html) feature, which allows you to add several attributes to your code: `[CanBeNull]`, `[NotNull]`, `[ItemCanBeNull]`, `[ItemNotNull]`. The nullability analysis performed by the plugin will take these attributes into account, resulting in the compile-time warnings you ask for.

Comment: What has the compiler to do with that?

Comment: Well, I imagine the compiler theoretically could make a complex analysis and generate warnings when one does not check for null where he should. But you are right, this is more of a language feature than a compiler one. I'll reword this.

Answer (score 6):

In short, no.

But it is currently a proposal for future development

[Proposal: Nullable reference types and nullability checking](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5032)

Comment: As of December 2019, this feature has finally arrived. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/embracing-nullable-reference-types/ for details